# force remove .php extension in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i know there are many questions like "How do i remove the .php extension, so that /test/ will be /test.php"
but if the user directly goes to test.php it doesnt replace the extension.
So I want to replace the .php it should be /.
here is the part of the .htacces I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule stuff\.php /other_stuff/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What you should do is to **redirect** user from `/file.php` to `/file/`.

Comment: a redirect issues an infinite loop :/

Comment: When I think about it, I had the same problem. I'm sure I just gave up back then. So good luck :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the check against the actual request instead of the URI (which gets rewritten by other rules). The `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable doesn't change in the course of the rewrite engine. Try adding these rules right below the `RewriteEngine` directive:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /([^/]+)\.php(\?|\ |$)
RewriteRule ^ /%2/ [L,R=301]
```